# 500 Internal Server Error when uploading large files to MediaWiki

Tags: configuration, timeout, mediawiki, upload, files

When I upload a large (>245 Mb) file to my MediaWiki wiki (using Upload file, same as for images), I see:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

This is a `.avi` file. I have set this as a permissible file type in LocalSettings.php.

How can I solve this? Is there a time out for uploading files (though this takes less than 10 seconds)?

Increasing the memory to 1024M did **not** work:

> ini_set( 'memory_limit', '1024M' );

Comment: What do your webserver logs say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check upload_max_filesize in /etc/php.ini

Comment: @B14D3 - ironically, I posted the same solution at the same time as you. Thanks, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Wikis Actually, you beat him by 24 seconds :)

Comment: @squillman - how do you know?

Comment: @Wikis Hover your mouse over the "answered X hours/days ago" text on a post and it shows the exact time the post was entered in the database.

Comment: @squillman - and again I've learnt something - thanks!

Comment: :D good one :D same time ... I'm glad I could help :D

Answer (score 1):

Solved - it appears that this was in `php.ini`:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the directory to which these image files are being uploaded has enough permissions, i dont suspect its timeout problem , the file size is not so big , its something to do with script which is handling this upload and writing to server in some dire